# Solidity Expected '(' but got identifier

Tags: solidity, contract-development, flash-loans, visual-studio-code, arbitrage

So I am working on a flash loan arbitrage in solidity and was coding the arbitrage logic when I got hit with

`Expected '(' but got identifier`

here is the code for the arbitrage

```
function startArbitrage(
address token0, 
address token1, 
uint amount0, 
uint amount1
  ) external {
address pairAddress = IUniswapV2Factory(factory).getPair(token0, token1);
require(pairAddress != address(0), 'This pool does not exist');
IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress).swap(
  amount0, 
  amount1 
  address(this), 
  bytes('not empty')
);
 }
```

I am working in vs code if that makes any difference thanks in advanced

Comment: , is missing after amount1 inside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out since its arbitrage logic and is in between curly brackets {} it can't have the word function

Answer (score 1):

You have unnecessary "," in your function parameters. Change to this

```
function startArbitrage(
address token0, 
address token1, 
uint amount0, 
uint amount1
```

Comment: tried it still doesn't work

Comment: Try to change the last parameter of the swap function to `new bytes(0)`. If it still doesn't work, please share the exact error message and where is it.

Comment: it doesn't work I'm getting the error on the word startArbitrage it has the red line it says Expected '(' but got identifier

Comment: You're also missing a "," after amount1 inside the swap function. That might be it